# Add values to dataframe based on existing unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe DF with 2 columns:

```
CLASS   STUDENT
'Sci'   'Francy'
'Sci'   Vacant
'math'  'Alex'
'math'  'Arthur'
'math'  'Katy'
'eng'   'Jack'
'eng'   Vacant
'eng'   'Francy'
'Hist'   'Francy'
'Hist'   'Francy'
```

I need all the classes to have 1 `vacant` student. Some of them already have.

RESULT

```
CLASS   STUDENT
'Sci'   'Francy'
'Sci'   Vacant
'math'  'Alex'
'math'  'Arthur'
'math'  'Katy'
'math'  Vacant
'eng'   'Jack'
'eng'   Vacant
'eng'   'Francy'
'Hist'   'Francy'
'Hist'   'Francy'
'Hist'   Vacant
```

I have tried

```
unique_class = DF['unique_class'].drop_duplicates()
vacant_column = pd.Series(['vacant'] * unique_class.shape[0])
temp_df = pd.concat([unique_class, vacant_column], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
DF = DF.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
DF.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

It works but it seems too much. Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```
# Copy of your data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "class": ["Sci", "Sci", "math", "math", "math", "eng", "eng", "eng", "Hist", "Hist"],
    "student": ["Francy", "vacant", "Alex", "Arthur", "Katy", "Jack", "vacant", "Francy", "Francy", "Francy"]
    })

# An identical DF with all students equal to "vacant"
vacant_df = pd.DataFrame({"class": df["class"], "student": "vacant"})

# Remove existing 'vacant' from original DF and concatenate with de-duplicated vacant dataframe (to avoid duplicate 'vacant' entries)
final_df = pd.concat([df.loc[df.student != "vacant", vacant_df.drop_duplicates("class")])
```

Original DF:

```
  class student
8  Hist  Francy
9  Hist  Francy
0   Sci  Francy
1   Sci  vacant
5   eng    Jack
6   eng  vacant
7   eng  Francy
2  math    Alex
3  math  Arthur
4  math    Katy
```

Final DF:

```
  class student
8  Hist  Francy
9  Hist  Francy
8  Hist  vacant
0   Sci  Francy
0   Sci  vacant
5   eng    Jack
7   eng  Francy
5   eng  vacant
2  math    Alex
3  math  Arthur
4  math    Katy
2  math  vacant
```

Comment: I'll upvote. However, my dataset is huge, can't afford to make a copy of the whole df. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the record, there is nothing wrong with your solution. You can achieve the same result in a "one-liner" using practically the same approach:

```
df = df.append(df[['CLASS']].drop_duplicates().assign(STUDENT='Vacant')).drop_duplicates()
```

[out]

```
  CLASS STUDENT
0   Sci  Francy
1   Sci  Vacant
2  math    Alex
3  math  Arthur
4  math    Katy
5   eng    Jack
6   eng  Vacant
7   eng  Francy
8  Hist  Francy
2  math  Vacant
8  Hist  Vacant
```

And if required, you can chain on `sort_values` and `reset_index` to make the table a bit more legible:

```
df = (df.append(df[['CLASS']].drop_duplicates().assign(STUDENT='Vacant'))
      .drop_duplicates()
      .sort_values('CLASS')
      .reset_index(drop=True))
```

[out]

```
   CLASS STUDENT
0   Hist  Francy
1   Hist  Vacant
2    Sci  Francy
3    Sci  Vacant
4    eng    Jack
5    eng  Vacant
6    eng  Francy
7   math    Alex
8   math  Arthur
9   math    Katy
10  math  Vacant
```

Comment: In your solution, math is missing vacant

Comment: don't think so..? 2nd bottom line?

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry

Comment: Your drop_duplicates should have inplace=True?

Comment: probably better to use assignment in this case... `df = ...` will update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.merge`

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'CLASS': df['CLASS'].unique(), 'STUDENT':'vacant'})

df_new.merge(df, how='outer', on=['CLASS','STUDENT'])

# Use `.sort_values(by='CLASS') if sorted df needed
```

Output:

```
    CLASS   STUDENT
0   Sci vacant
1   math    vacant
2   eng     vacant
3   Hist    vacant
4   Sci     Francy
5   math    Alex
6   math    Arthur
7   math    Katy
8   eng     Jack
9   eng     Francy
10  Hist    Francy
11  Hist    Francy
```